# Displaying an 11x11 Matrix on a Canvas

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to create a canvas that displays an 11x11 matrix.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasGame');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.scale(10, 10);

context.fillstyle = '#000';
context.fillstyle(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


const matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];
```

Depending on the number inside the matrix it will create a rectangle of a certain colour.
I've created a basic function that goes through every entry.


if = 0, white rectangle.
else, black rectangle.

```
function drawMatrix(matrix){
    matrix.forEach((row, y) =>{
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if(value === 0) {
                context.fillStyle = 'white';
                context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                context.fillStyle = 'black';
                context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
            }
        });
    });
}

drawMatrix(matrix);
```

However when I load my html file with my .js file and my canvas set-up it doesnt load anything apart from the styling I've applied to my canvas.

[Screenshot: What it loads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OruH5.png)

My HTML, if that matters.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Grounds</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #345;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
      }
      canvas {
        border: dashed .2em #fff;
        height: 90vh;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Zone</h1>
    <p>Using a canvas to display 11x11 matrix</p>
    <canvas id="canvasGame" width="350" height="350"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// every drawn pixel will be 16 times bigger
context.scale(canvas.height / 16, canvas.height / 16);

const matrix = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

function drawMatrix(matrix) {

  // write all pixels cycling thru rows and columns
  matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      context.fillStyle = value && "black" || "white";
      context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    });
  });
}

drawMatrix(matrix); // draw the matrix
```

```html
<center><canvas id="canvas" width=192 height=192></canvas></center>
```

Comment: Can you add a brief comment on what was not working for OP and how your code fixes it?

Comment: the line: ``context.fillstyle(``  is totally wrong in his code and must be removed.
also the line before that should read ``context.fillStyle`` with a capital S

Answer (score 0):

Here is also another way...

```js
const canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
const canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
const context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

//context.scale(canvas.height / 16, canvas.height / 16);

matrix = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

function drawMatrix(matrix) {
  z = matrix.map((c) => c.map((c) => c == 0 ? [255, 255, 255, 255] : [0, 0, 0, 255]));
  i = new ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray.from(z.flat(2)), 12)
  context1.putImageData(i, 0, 0);
  context2.scale(16, 16);
  context2.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  context2.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  context2.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  context2.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);


}

drawMatrix(matrix);
```

```html
<center><canvas hidden id="canvas1" width=12 height=12></canvas></center>
<center><canvas id="canvas2" width=192 height=192></canvas></center>
```

Answer (score -1):

The rectangles you're creating are 1 by 1 pixel and always in the upper-left. You should calculate the width/height of the rectangle (width / 11, height / 11). Then translate the x and width using those values. Something like the following should work:

```
function drawMatrix(matrix){
    var cellWidth = canvas.width / 11.0;
    var cellHeight = vanvas.height / 11.0;

    matrix.forEach((row, y) =>{
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            context.fillStyle = cellColor(value);
            context.fillRect(x * cellWidth, y * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
        });
    });
}
function cellColor(val) {
    if(value == 0)
    {
        return 'white';
    }

    return 'black';
}

drawMatrix(matrix);
```

This will calculate the width and height of the cell, loop through each element, and draw the rectangle with either white or black depending on the value.

You should also make sure that the drawMatrix function is called after the body is loaded.

Comment: Using the code you provided I am still only having my canvas show up and nothing else. [link](https://gyazo.com/922a1fdcf4a1bcb59562988fcddd3458) <. screenshot of my JS.

Comment: your code is wrong, dude.